# How to check if a GPU is an OpenCL compatible GPU supporting the OpenCL extension cl_khr_byte_addressable_store and image objects

Tags: gpu

I'm using the computer vision library MVTec Halcon.  I've gotten Halcon to work well with an NVIDIA GTX 1070/1080 in a desktop computer and with a Quadro P2000 in a server.

However, I can't seem to get Halcon to work with the Pascal GPU inside a TX2.

I found the following in the Halcon documentation:

```
At present, HALCON only supports OpenCL compatible GPUs supporting the OpenCL extension cl_khr_byte_addressable_store and image objects. If you are not sure whether a certain device is supported, please refer to the manufacturer.
```

How can I check on the TX2 if it `supports OpenCL compatible GPUs supporting the OpenCL extension cl_khr_byte_addressable_store and image objects`?

The TX2 runs a slightly NVIDIA-modified version of Ubuntu 16.04 and the NVIDIA software to flash the TX2 installs CUDA 9.0 and cuDNN 7.1 on the TX2 if that matters.  I have gotten both OpenCV and TensorFlow to successfully use the Pascal GPU in the TX2 so I know the hardware is good.

Comment: Huh.  https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1010166/jetson-tx2/does-jetson-tx1-or-tx2-support-opencl/  basically says "no, we don't  support that."

Comment: Mokubai thanks for the link.  I installed JetPack 3.3 on my Ubuntu 16.04 host, which installs CUDA and the other stuff to work with the TX2, then it flashes the TX2 as well.  The link you provided is very strange b/c Halcon works great GPU-accelerated on my Ubuntu 16.04 Host with a GTX 1080 and I didn't install OpenCL on my desktop host.  Can you advise how I can check if OpenCL is installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some Googling I've worked out how to check if OpenCL is installed and if a certain extension is supported:

```
sudo apt-get install clinfo
clinfo
```

On my desktop where Halcon works with the GPU this yields:

```
$ clinfo
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
  Platform Vendor                                 NVIDIA Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 10.0.132
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer
  Platform Extensions function suffix             NV

  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     GeForce GTX 1080
  Device Vendor                                   NVIDIA Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x10de
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
  Driver Version                                  415.27
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Topology (NV)                            PCI-E, 01:00.0
  Max compute units                               20
  Max clock frequency                             1733MHz
  Compute Capability (NV)                         6.1
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     1
    Supported partition types                     None
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             1024x1024x64
  Max work group size                             1024
  Preferred work group size multiple              32
  Warp size (NV)                                  32
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                 1 / 1       
    short                                                1 / 1       
    int                                                  1 / 1       
    long                                                 1 / 1       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                1 / 1       
    double                                               1 / 1        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  Yes
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              8511488000 (7.927GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           2127872000 (1.982GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              No
  Integrated memory (NV)                          No
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       4096 bits (512 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        327680
  Global Memory cache line                        128 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             32
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            134217728 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Max 2D image size                             16384x32768 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             16384x16384x16384 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 256
    Max number of write image args                16
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               49152 (48KiB)
  Registers per block (NV)                        65536
  Max constant buffer size                        65536 (64KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     9
  Max size of kernel argument                     4352 (4.25KiB)
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Prefer user sync for interop                    No
  Profiling timer resolution                      1000ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            No
    Kernel execution timeout (NV)                 Yes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution (NV)       Yes
    Number of async copy engines                  2
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels                                
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  No platform
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              Success [NV]
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No platform
```

Critically, `cl_khr_byte_addressable_store` is listed under `Device Extensions`.

On the TX2, `clinfo` yields:

```
Number of platforms     0
```

So it seems I need to figure out a way to install OpenCL on this TX2, if this is even possible, which in any case is a different post entirely.